# cakephp call set array in controler

Tags: php, cakephp

I was wondering is it possible to call back an array/string in my controller that I set with

```
$this->set('gainedTotal', $this->Member->Point->gainedTotal());
```

I need to use the value latter in the method to make a calculation. I could store it in a variable of course but I am trying to practice keeping my code simple and clean so I was thinking that since it is already stored I could call it back.

I have tried things like

```
$this->request->gainedMonth
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it is accessible.

I would suggest doing it the route you mentioned and just creating a variable:

```
$gainedTotal = $this->Member->Point->gainedTotal();
$this->set('gainedTotal', $gainedTotal);
```

You can also 'set' many variables at once, which helps keep your code clean:

```
$gainedTotal = $this->Member->Point->gainedTotal();
$something = "pizza";
$dessert = "more pizza";
$this->set(compact('gainedTotal', 'something', 'dessert'));
```

Personally, I'm not a fan of calling methods within a `set()`.  Just doesn't seem clean logic (personal taste), and I almost always have to come back to add other variables or options to my `find()`...etc - meaning I would then need more than one `$this->set()` line, and further clutter my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep the variable for later in the same controller, I would recommend you to store it in a Session using the `session` component.

```
$this->Session->write('nameOfVariable', $variable);
```

And read it later with:

```
$this->Session->read('nameOfVariable');
```

Comment: Why would you store it in the cache if you're just planning on using again in the same method?  A normal PHP $variable would work just fine.

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood the question , but he said that he want to use it **later** in the same controller.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the reply. I actual wont need it latter in the controller. It is in the same method a couple of lines apart. I thought there might be a simpler way of storing once with the $this->set.